# Filter Laravel collection based on age from birthday in model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Okay, I'm pulling hair out with this one:

I'm using Laravel/Eloquent and PHP.  I have a `Cadet` model, which has a `DATE` field for date of birth called `birthday`.

In a controller, I'm retrieving a Collection of `Cadet` models that meet various criteria, but I'd like to filter the Collection based on the age of each `Cadet` too (i.e. the `$output` Collection should only have `Cadet` models above a minimum age.)

`$activity->age_min` is the minimum age (integer) I am wanting to filter the Collection by.

So, this is what I've been trying to do:

```
$output = $cadets->where('*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, CURDATE()) AS age', '>', $activity->age_min);
```

Problem is, I'm getting an empty array as a result despite knowing that at least two `Cadet` records fulfill the criteria.  If I add `->get();` to the end, the db falls over.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this to work so that `$output` contains a Collection of `Cadet` models with ages above `$activity->age_min`?

UPDATE

Okay, well, I've tried btl's suggestions and can't get them to work as I need to work out the age of each cadet and compare it with an integer to decide whether to exclude them or not.

I've had a play with lesssugar's idea below and got this far:

```
// Work out a date for which people must be born after
      $max_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($activity->date_from)->subYears($activity->age_min);
      // Filter the collection
      $output = $cadets->filter(function ($cadet) {
          return $cadet->birthday > $max_date;
      });
```

... but I'm going round in circles trying to work out how to use the Filter function and get it to only return Cadets whose birth date is more recent than $max_date.

I think I've been at this for too long today so I'm stepping away for a while. Any help or suggestions (and especially answers!) would be gratefully received! :)

Comment: As suggested, you could use Carbon, in combination with the [filter()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-filter) collection method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after some thought this is what I came up with:

```
      // Work out a date for which people must be born BEFORE to be included
      $max_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($activity->date_from)->subYears($activity->age_min);
      // Filter the collection
      $cadets = $cadets->filter(function($cadet) use ($max_date) {
              if (\Carbon\Carbon::parse($cadet->birthday)->lte($max_date)) {
                    return true;
              }
          }
      });
```

Thanks to @lesssugar for the filter() suggestion. Firstly using Carbon it's easy to create a date (minus the age limit) that is the threshold for determining if a cadet is old enough or not to be included in the collection (`$max_date`).

Then I run a filter on the existing collection and only pick out the records I'm interested in that have a birthday less than or equal to `$max_date`.

Originally I was thinking I could do this in a single query, but this is the solution I've arrived at and hopefully isn't too much more work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Carbon, it can handle these kind of date comparisons and so much easily.

```
$cadets = Cadet::where(Carbon::parse('birthday'), '>=', $activity->age_min)->get();
```

or

```
$cadets = Cadet::all()->each(function($cadet) use ($activity) {
    return Carbon::parse($cadet->birthday)->gt(Carbon::parse($activity->age_min);
});
```

Comment: Ah okay - I've tried the first suggestion but I'm getting the following error:

`DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (birthday) at position 0 (b): The timezone could not be found in the database`

Any ideas?

Comment: What format is birthday stored? date time string? timestamp? Post an example if you will.

Comment: birthday is a 'DATE' field in the db. Here's an example of the format - `2000-05-23`...  Surely `Carbon::parse('birthday')` is just trying to parse the string 'birthday' in the first example, rather than the field named birthday?

Comment: oh duh, yeah my mistake. Parse $cadet->birthday before the query and pass a variable in place of Carbon::parse('birthday')

Comment: Sorry, my db-fu is not very strong at all - I'm trying to do this all in one query if possible - is something like this not possible?

`$cadets = Cadet::where(Carbon::parse(birthday), '>=', $activity->age_min)->get();`

...rather than iterating through every model in the collection to parse their birthday and query the db on that?

Comment: Use the 2nd example I posted using Cadet::all(), It only executes one 'select * from cadets' then stores the results in a collection in memory. Come to think of it, $cadets = Cadet::where('birthday', '>=', Carbon::parse($activity->age_min))->get(); may work too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146785/discussion-between-nockieboy-and-btl).